# .net core: run big tasks in the background

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, background-task

I created a .net core web api project. It has gotten kinda big and I want to program a "delete" operation which deletes a lot of stuff from the database. Since there are a lot of things to delete, this will be a long running process. So I thought maybe I can run this in the background and just write status updates somewhere for the user to see whats happening.

I googled this and I found BackgroundWorkerQueue and thought this might be my solution.

So I registered the service and everything and here is my method that calls it:

```
public class DeleteController : ControllerBase {

    private readonly BackgroundWorkerQueue _backgroundWorkerQueue;

    public AdminController(BackgroundWorkerQueue backgroundWorkerQueue){
        _backgroundWorkerQueue = backgroundWorkerQueue;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> HugeDeleteMethod(int id)
    {
        // some prechecks here... 

        // and here I thought I'd start the background task
        _backgroundWorkerQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
        {
            var a = _context.StatusTable.Find(id);
            a.Status += "Blablablabla\n";
            _context.StatusTable.Update(a);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //now start doing delete operations
        });
    }
}
```

And that class looks like this:

```
public class BackgroundWorkerQueue
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> _workItems = new ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>();
    private SemaphoreSlim _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);

        return workItem;
    }

    public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
        _signal.Release();
    }
}
```

There is also a DeleteService, which is also called in my startup, but I am not sure what it does:

```
public class DeleteService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorkerQueue queue;

    public NukeService(BackgroundWorkerQueue queue)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await queue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            await workItem(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Both are added in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddHostedService<DeleteService>();
services.AddSingleton<BackgroundWorkerQueue>();
```

Well, maybe I'm going about this all wrong. This is never called it seems, the StatusTable field "Status" is always empty. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to subclass `BackgroundService` class or implement `IHostedService` and than register your service as hosted service.
This will run a service in the background. Than in your service you can leverage the BlockingQueue that will perform tasks only when they are added, e.g. like this:

```
public class MyService : BackgroundService {

private readonly BlockingCollection<long> queue;

  public MyService(){
     this.queue = new BlockingCollection<long>();
     Task.Run(async () => await this.Execute());
  }

  public void AddId(long id) {
     this.queue.Add(id);
  }

  private async Task Execute()
  {
      foreach (var id in this.queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
      {
            ... do your stuff ...
      }
   }     
}


services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
```

Here is the docu: [Background services in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I did that, there is a DeleteService : BackgroundService that is called in the startup.cs with addHostedService - but still, it doesnt work

Comment: Is the constructor of the service called on the startup? Do you get into the Execute method? If both are yes, then probably your problem is elsewhere, e.g. that background code does work, but deletion code does not.

Comment: I edited my code to show you exactly how it looks like.

Comment: and yes, my ExecuteAsync is called, a breakpoint in there is reached

Comment: is the code inside workItem called? If not, can it be the semaphore? It looks ok, but still... What you are trying to solve there with the semaphore can be solved with a BlockingCollection on a higher level. The loop will be run only if there are items in the collection.